# Showing Current Date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

Is there any way I could show the current date on a report without using the SELECT statement?? I dont even want to write it manually I want the system to show the current date itself in the heading of the report.

Comment: This sounds like a question for whatever reporting engine you are using, not a SQL question

Comment: How is the report being generated?

Comment: im using Oracle SQL Plus window where u could run SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Reporting Services, you should be able to add a new field to the header then right click the field > expression > Category: Built-in Fields Item: Execution Time

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in show-date-at-top-of-each-page function in sqlplus, you have to work this around. I would use [TTITLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12048.htm) and select date from dual prior to running report.

```
12:59:29 SYSTEM@dwal> col now new_value header_date;
12:59:31 SYSTEM@dwal> select to_char(sysdate, 'ddmmyyyy hh24miss') as now from dual;

NOW
---------------
03042013 125944

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
12:59:40 SYSTEM@dwal> def header_date
DEFINE HEADER_DATE     = "03042013 125944" (CHAR)
13:03:28 SYSTEM@dwal> ttitle left '&header_date'
13:03:32 SYSTEM@dwal> set pagesize 10
13:03:36 SYSTEM@dwal> select rownum from dual connect by rownum <= 20;

03042013 125944
    ROWNUM
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6

03042013 125944
    ROWNUM
----------
         7
         8
         9
        10
        11
        12

03042013 125944
    ROWNUM
----------
        13
        14
        15
        16
        17
        18

03042013 125944
    ROWNUM
----------
        19
        20

20 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

But if you insist on not having to perform a single additional select - the general idea stays the same, to use a substitution variable. Probably you can pass a current date parameter from your shell while starting sqlplus and refer to it as `&1` in your TTITLE specification.